# How to say "both arguments must have the same type" in Java?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

In unit testing, you sometimes want a method like this one:

```java
<V> void checkEq(V expectation, V value) {
  if (!expectation.equals(value))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("not equal");
}
```

(assume for a second that we can't use junit for some reason) The idea is that the compiler should ensure both arguments have *the* *same* *type*.
However the compiler doesn't complain about this invocation, where the types obviously differ:

```java
checkEq(1, "");
```

I've tried some variations of this, like `checkEq(V expectation, Supplier<V> value)` and `checkEq(1, () -> "")`. It seems like the compiler is always happy to insert `Object` for `V`. Is there some way to tell the compiler not to use the trivial `Object` solution?

Comment: Those two arguments _are_ the same type; they're both `Object`. What more specifically do you want? (Saying that they have to be the exact same class isn't suitable, either, since usually an `ArrayList` and a `LinkedList` are interchangeable.)

Comment: It's possible `1` is been auto boxed into a `Integer`, and `String` and `Integer` are both `Object`s

Comment: Well, you could always manually state the required type, e.g. `YourClass.<String>checkEq(...)` or by adding a class parameter like `checkEq(Class<V> type, V exp, V actual)`.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas this is obviously true. It's a bit sad because then you actually pass the solution yourself, so the compiler doesn't do type inference at all. But I'm afraid that's not possible with current Java compiler.

Comment: Well, the compiler does its best to resolve the type but that could yield unwanted results as in your case. If you're not satisfied with the result of type inference you need to tell the compiler what exactly you'd expect. This isn't necessarily the exact type but basically the upper bound you expect, e.g. `YourClass.<Number>checkEq(Integer.valueOf(1), Double.valueOf(2))` would work perfectly fine by accepting numbers only. Btw, a 3rd option along the same lines might be to use a return type for inference, e.g. `String v = checkEq(1, "");` (and of course return one of the parameters).

Comment: The compiler _does_ perform type inference and uses the most restrictive type it can find to make the existing code compile. That's `Object` in your case; what class would you expect it to infer?

Comment: daniu, I was looking for a way to tell the compiler not to accept `Object`. So the solution I was hoping for is "none" (compilation fails).

Comment: maybe you should outline your whole idea, because looking at the comments you made - you're not really looking for this method since somehow you're making a builder now.

Comment: shark, no that's not really relevant, I've deleted that comment to avoid confusion. "M A"'s answer is just another way to pass the solution explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

If you declare the type parameter as part of a wrapper class, then it's possible to infer the type and enforce that the expected and value follow it:

```
class CheckEq<V> {
    void checkEq(V expectation, V value) {        
        if (!expectation.equals(value))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not equal");
    }
}
```

But I feel this is an over-engineering practice, because you just want to do an `equals()` at the end (on two `Object`s), so type safety is secondary to that.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, compile-time type safety is insufficient. The problem in this case is the developer, and a developer can make any invocation in such a scenario, by twisting the compiler if necessary.

If you, as the API developer, are so desperate to assist your callers make the correct invocation, you can add a third, `Class`-typed parameter that limits potential incorrect calls

```
<V> void checkEq(Class<V> cls, V expectation, V value) {
    if (!expectation.equals(value))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("not equal");
}
```

I don't know what you would call such a parameter. But that code can't be called with either of these

```
checkEq(String.class, 1, "");
checkEq(Integer.class, 1, "");
```

However, the lazy kind will still be able to call it in this way, although it (supposedly) will be obvious to them that they're doing something wrong:

```
checkEq(Object.class, 1, "");
```

The only effective way to limit the problem is to make it fail at runtime. This way you force the developer to test.

```
if (expectation.getClass() != value.getClass() || !expectation.equals(value))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("not equal");
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the comments received so far, apparently that's just not how the Java compiler currently works. All answers and comments boil down to "just pass the explicit solution" in some form or other. Let's hope we get an improvement (some annotation or other compiler hint maybe) in the future to say "solution has to be better than `X`" (in particular `X=Object`).